# `projectile-find-file` completions display in the mini-buffer rather than in a separate `helm` window

Tags: helm-projectile

My Emacs system satisfies the following three conditions:

1. The Emacs packages `helm` and `helm-projectile` are installed on it.
2. The directory `~/MyProj/` is recognized as a `projectile` project (it is a Git directory).
3. `~/MyProj/` contains the following text files (and possibly other files):

   - `README.md`
   - `file1`
   - `file2`

Consider the following scenario:

1. Open a new Emacs session.
2. Execute `M-x cd <RET> ~/MyProj <RET>` to switch the default directory to the project directory.
3. Execute `C-c p f` to run the `projectile-find-file` command.

The mini-buffer now displays:

> [-] Find file: {README.md | file1 | file2}

[image: projectile-find-file]

Why are the completions listed horizontally in the mini-buffer rather than vertically in a separate `helm` window, as is the norm with `helm` commands? Compare the above screencap to the following, resulting from executing `C-x c C-x C-f` (= `helm-find-files`).

[image: helm-find-files]

I find the latter display style more convenient that the former. Is it possible to view the results of the various `projectile` commands this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `projectile-completion-system` to helm:

```
(setq projectile-completion-system 'helm)
```

Or try enabling `helm-projectile` like this:

```
(helm-projectile-on)
```

Comment: Thanks. Are you sure the second line is necessary? It appears to work fine without it.

Comment: I'm not sure, the doc says it just enables some keybindings.

Comment: Which doc? Could you please provide a link?

Comment: `M-x describe-function RET helm-projectile-on RET`

Comment: The second line may be helpful in general, but I think it is not necessary for solving the issue I described in my original post.

Comment: I think I've figured out what the `helm-projectile-on` function do: It routes every invocation of a `projectile-...` function to the corresponding `helm-projectile-...` function. So, for example, while executing `C-c p f` normally invoke the `projectile-find-files` function, if the `helm-projectile-on` function is in effect (e.g. if it's been invoked when `.emacs` was loaded), then the `helm-projectile-find-files` function will be invoked instead. Thus the two lines in your answer describe two alternative ways to accomplish the same result. There is no need to use them simultaneously.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

`C-c p h` will ask you to select a project. It will then launch the `projectile-find-files` command with a `helm`-style completion list. In fact, all the `helm-projectile...` commands (e.g. `helm-projectile`, which is bound to `C-c p h`), will employ `helm`-style completion lists. See [here](https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile).